# Can I remove unwanted http headers Server, X-AspNet-Version and X-AspNetMvc-Version using global.asax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax

I have used the following code shown below.
This removes the headers but is this the right way to do it? Should I go for another approach as many posts suggest?

I have added this code and it removes the unwanted headers but I'm new to handling these headers. Want to know if this is how it is done.

```
    protected void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders()
    {
        Response.Headers.Remove("Server");
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNet-Version");
        Response.Headers.Remove("X-AspNetMvc-Version");
    }
```

-

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach really...use whatever works. You can do it here, or in web config, or via IIS settings. Doesn't matter a great deal. The advantage of embedding it into web config or code is that the setting travels with the app when you deploy to different environments. Alternatively an advantage of doing it via IIS settings would be that it applies to all apps deployed to that website. Depends on your needs

Answer (score 5):

Don't see anything wrong with your approach except you are doing it at runtime where as this can be handled with the following too.

Add this to web.config to get rid of the X-AspNet-Version header:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
</system.web>
```

To remove X-AspNetMvc-Version Add the following in the `Application_Start` event on Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
}
```